# audio won't play from within .jar

Tags: java, class, audio, jar, wav

I've been creating a program that plays the audio files within it's own jar file and I'm having problems with getting the audio file to actually play.

```
public class soundPlayer
{
    public String currentSound ="";
    public soundPlayer(String soundName)
    {
        currentSound = soundName;
    }

    public void playSound()
    {
        try
        {
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass()
                              .getResourceAsStream("/"+currentSound)));
                clip.start();
            }

         catch (Exception exc)

        {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        exc.printStackTrace(System.out);

        }
}
```

This is the soundPlayer class. I've gotten a similar class to work with files outside of the jar file but I can't get it to work from within.

An important thing to note about this class is that it does seem to detect that the file exists because if i change the file name, I get a null pointer exception so the file is being seen but just not playing. I've looked at several threads on this but none of their solutions have worked for me.

Update: I suppose to put things more clearly, When I try to play the andio after the file is compiled, it requires that the the wave file be in the same folder as the Jar which i'm sure you can imagine how that can be a bad thing.

Comment: I'm not really sure what that is so probably not.